# Laravel API using modified 'MustVerifyApiEmail' and custom 'EnsureApiEmailIsVerified' middleware can't pick up request user

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, verification

I have using Laravel 6.x as a backend with an external (different domain) Vue frontend and do not have register user functionality. The way I register users is by importing batches of users using the Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel package - which works great.

So when each user is created a job is created by sending each user an email verification link, which when they login for the first time they will need to change their password and simultaneously their email gets marked as verified - which also should work fine.

The problem is that with the already created factory of users, who have their email_verified_at field filled - and the newly imported users - I cannot login as the custom EnsureEmailApiIsVerified middleware does not have access to the $request->user(). I figured out that I can specify the auth guard of 'api' such as $request->user('api') which then can pick up the user, but only of their Bearer token (using Laravel Passport) is sent with the request.

This does make sense as how else would the system know who the request user is without some identifier such as the token. But then how does the standard 'implements MustVerifyEmail' on the User model and subsequent standard 'EnsureEmailIsVerified' middelware on the web routes pick up the $request->user()?

It would stand to reason that either both (standard and my custom) middleware should have access to the $request->user() or both should not.

Now I have had to modify and bring out quite a few framework controllers into my App\Http directory but I have copied them almost verbatim just changing a few things to ensure it works with my API routes - because setting the default guard to 'api' instead of 'web' in config/auth.php had not used it as a default throughout my controllers as thought to be.

So here are the steps I followed:

Created a custom middleware and attached it to the entire 'api' middleware group in App\Http\Kernel.php

```
/**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
            'verifiedapi',

        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'role' => \App\Http\Middleware\HasRole::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'verifiedapi' => \App\Http\Middleware\EnsureApiEmailIsVerified::class,
    ];
```

Then here is that custom 'EnsureApiEmailIsVerified' middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\Auth\MustVerifyApiEmail;

class EnsureApiEmailIsVerified
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (! $request->user('api') ||
            ($request->user('api') instanceof MustVerifyApiEmail &&
            ! $request->user('api')->hasVerifiedEmail())) {
            return abort(403, 'Your email has not yet been verified.');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

You will see that references an instance of my custom 'MustVerifyApiEmail' which is a trait that is used on the User Model, with the only diversion from the standard trait being the public function 'sendApiEmailVerificationNotification' as such:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API\Auth;

use App\Notifications\VerifyApiEmail;

trait MustVerifyApiEmail
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user has verified their email address.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasVerifiedEmail()
    {
        return ! is_null($this->email_verified_at);
    }

    /**
     * Mark the given user's email as verified.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function markEmailAsVerified()
    {
        return $this->forceFill([
            'email_verified_at' => $this->freshTimestamp(),
        ])->save();
    }

    /**
     * Send the email verification notification.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendApiEmailVerificationNotification()
    {
        $this->notify(new VerifyApiEmail);
    }

    /**
     * Get the email address that should be used for verification.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmailForVerification()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

This new 'sendApiEmailVerificationNotification()' notifies the $request-user('api') with a custom VerifyApiEmail Notification, as such:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class VerifyApiEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * The callback that should be used to build the mail message.
     *
     * @var \Closure|null
     */
    public static $toMailCallback;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Build the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $verificationUrl = $this->verificationUrl($notifiable);

        if (static::$toMailCallback) {
            return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable, $verificationUrl);
        }

        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject(Lang::get('Verify Email Address'))
            ->line(Lang::get('Please click the button below to verify your email address.'))
            ->action(Lang::get('Verify Email Address'), $verificationUrl)
            ->line(Lang::get('If you did not create an account, no further action is required.'));
    }

    /**
     * Get the verification URL for the given notifiable.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return string
     */
    protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
    {
        return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
            'verification.api.verify',
            Carbon::now()->addMinutes(Config::get('auth.verification.expire', 60)),
            [
                'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
                'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Set a callback that should be used when building the notification mail message.
     *
     * @param  \Closure  $callback
     * @return void
     */
    public static function toMailUsing($callback)
    {
        static::$toMailCallback = $callback;
    }
}
```

The new api routes are as follows:

```
Route::namespace('API\Auth')->group(function () {
    Route::post('login', 'PassportController@login');
    Route::post('refresh', 'PassportController@refresh');
    Route::post('logout', 'PassportController@logout');
    Route::get('email/verify/{id}/{hash}', 'VerificationApiController@verify')->name('verification.api.verify');
    Route::get('email/resend', 'VerificationApiController@resend')->name('api.verification.resend');
});
```

And the VerificationApiController is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;

class VerificationApiController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Show the email verification notice.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Mark the authenticated user's email address as verified.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
     */
    public function verify(Request $request)
    {
        if (! hash_equals((string) $request->route('id'), (string) $request->user('api')->getKey())) {
            throw new AuthorizationException;
        }

        if (! hash_equals((string) $request->route('hash'), sha1($request->user('api')->getEmailForVerification()))) {
            throw new AuthorizationException;
        }

        if ($request->user('api')->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Email already verified'], 422);
        }

        if ($request->user('api')->markEmailAsVerified()) {
            event(new Verified($request->user('api')));
        }

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Email verified!']);
    }

    /**
     * Resend the email verification notification.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function resend(Request $request)
    {
        $request->user('api')->sendApiEmailVerificationNotification();

        return response()->json(['success' => 'Email verification has been resent!']);
    }
}
```

I also noticed that onn the User Model it extends User as Authenticatable which then uses the standard MustVerifyEmail' - so I brought that out of the framework as well and changed the usage to the new MustVerifyApiEmail - like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\Auth\MustVerifyApiEmail;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements
    AuthenticatableContract,
    AuthorizableContract,
    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword, MustVerifyApiEmail;
}
```

My User model then looks like this at the top:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\Auth\MustVerifyApiEmailInterface;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyApiEmailInterface
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
...
```

As you can see it's quite a bit of customization - but it should all work in theory and I am getting no errors that I can use. Here are the errors that I get:

When I login with a user who's email is verified or even not verified, I get the error that the user's email has not been verified - but only because it doesn't pick up the $request->user('api'). When I try to throw an error in the middleware itself before returning the request dumping the $request->user('api') it gives me null

So my question is, with the standard middleware of 'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class, - how does this pick up the $request->user()?

Is there something I am missing or am I going about this the wrong way? It seems that when the user logs in it doesn't log them in and then run the middleware - so there is no $request->user('api') - maybe because I am using Passport, but I would think that what should happen is that the middleware needs to run after it has authenticated the user then it would have access to the $request->user('api')

ANY GUIDANCE WOULD BE EXTREMELY APPRECIATED!

api.php

```
Route::prefix('email')->middleware(['auth:api'])->group(function () {
  Route::get('resend', 'VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');
  Route::get('verify/{id}/{hash}', 'VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
});
```

Comment: Do your routes have the `auth:api` middleware?

Comment: @ArunAS Yes... Route::prefix('email')->middleware(['auth:api'])->group(function () {
  Route::get('resend', 'VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');
  Route::get('verify/{id}/{hash}', 'VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
});